# ASP.Net C# LINQ to Entities Lambda expression casting result

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, linq-to-entities

Get intellisense error on return statement:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "system.Link.IQueryable to
>   Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

```
    public IEnumerable<int> addResApp(string RestName, string RestStreet, string RestCity, string RestZip, string RestPhone, string ContactFname, string ContactLname, string ContactEmail, string ContactPhone)
    {
        APP_REST appRest = new APP_REST();
        appRest.APP_REST_NAME = RestName;
        appRest.APP_REST_STREET = RestStreet;
        appRest.APP_REST_CITY = RestCity;
        appRest.APP_REST_ZIP = RestZip;
        appRest.APP_REST_PHONE = RestPhone;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_FNAME = ContactFname;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_LNAME = ContactLname;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_EMAIL = ContactEmail;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_PHONE = ContactPhone;
        db.AddToAPP_REST(appRest);

        //Return the ID of the added record
        var AppRestID = from APP_REST in db.APP_REST
                 group APP_REST by APP_REST.APP_CODE into grp
                 select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.APP_CODE).Last();
        return AppRestID;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I got it working .... finally.  Everyone helped a bit, but I finally put the answer together based on the help I received.   THANKS everyone!

```
public class DLaddRestApp
{

    RestaurantsEntities db = new RestaurantsEntities();

    public IEnumerable<int> addResApp(string RestName, string RestStreet, string RestCity, string RestZip, string RestPhone, string ContactFname, string ContactLname, string ContactEmail, string ContactPhone)
    {
        APP_REST appRest = new APP_REST();
        appRest.APP_REST_NAME = RestName;
        appRest.APP_REST_STREET = RestStreet;
        appRest.APP_REST_CITY = RestCity;
        appRest.APP_REST_ZIP = RestZip;
        appRest.APP_REST_PHONE = RestPhone;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_FNAME = ContactFname;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_LNAME = ContactLname;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_EMAIL = ContactEmail;
        appRest.APP_CONTACT_PHONE = ContactPhone;
        appRest.APP_DESC_CUISINE = "";
        db.AddToAPP_REST(appRest);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var appRestId = from APP_REST in db.APP_REST
                orderby APP_REST.APP_CODE ascending
                select APP_REST.APP_CODE;

        return appRestId;        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of your method doesn't seem to match what you're trying to return.  Admittedly, the error message isn't entirely helpful in its casting attempt.  I guess the compiler isn't following `.Last()` to its logical conclusion.  But either way, the error does point to the problem...

- Your method advertises that it returns `IEnumerable<int>`, which is a series of integers.
- Your method tries to actually return a *single* integer by calling `.Last()` (MSDN information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx).)

If I were the code calling this method, I'd be confused with the result.  Should the method signature be changed to simply `int`, or should you omit the `.Last()` and return all of the integers?  The method name doesn't offer me any clues as to what it's logically supposed to do, so the decision is yours.

Comment: I started with a return type of 'int' first but had a similar problem with the error of:  Cannot implicity convert type System.Link.IQueryable<DL_APP_REST> to int.

Comment: @Susan: What is the type coming from the query?  Maybe you need another transform in the `select`?  Are you selecting only integers from the data, or entire records?  Looking back at it now, I think you may be selecting entire records.  On the last line, _after_ evaluating the LINQ expression, what is the data type of `AppRestID`?  Maybe it _contains_ the `int` you're looking for and you should be returning that property instead of the whole thing?

Comment: I'm trying to return the ID of the record that I just added to the database; the datatype is an integer.  I've tried using both a return type of List<APP_REST> and int.  I get casting errors with both.  Sorry, I'm really a newbie with LINQ

Answer (score 1):

I would try first by simplifying the LINQ expression and then inspecting the type of AppRestId.  When you remove the Last() and OrderByDescending() you are selecting a list of ordered APP_REST (IEnumerable>).

When you add the OrderByDescending() you are then selecting IEnumerable, so, still an enumerable list of APP_REST, not of int.

When you call Last(), you are selecting the last set of grouped entries, still not ints.

If you want to return ints you are going to have to get the Key of the group at some point.  You can do this all in nice LINQ syntax as such:

```
        var appRestId = from APP_REST in rests
                        group APP_REST by APP_REST.APP_CODE
                        into grp
                        orderby grp.Key descending
                        select grp.Key;
```

If you want to get just the last APP_CODE you can call Last() on appRestId.  I would ask myself if I really want to return IEnumberable or just int.  I'm assuming that you will always only have one APP_CODE per added APP_REST.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the integor ID of the item I just added to the database (the 'last' item).  Should I use a return type of int in my function? I keep getting errors on casting when I do.

Comment: If you are trying to get the integer added then you have to return int.  Keep in mind that if the database is going to be used by more than one process at the same time then this method is not going to be reliable as you cannot assure that there is not another process adding  an item at the same time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following.  Should my signature be:  public IEnumerable<int>?